# misaligned_stack_error after moving some code into external framework (Cocoa)

Tags: cocoa, xcode, frameworks, stack

I just moved a bunch of code into a separate framework. Nothing has changed in the code since the move and it compiles fine. However, on runtime, It crashes with "misaligned_stack_error". I've been looking around and some people are saying -mstackrealign fixes it, however I have added it to the C flags for both projects in Xcode and it still crashes, exactly the same way.

(Please note the format of the projects: a framework, loaded into a plugin, which installs into some 3rd party software).

I'd greatly appreciate some help to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing either the code or the backtrace at the point of the crash, it is impossible to precisely say what is wrong.

Shooting a rubberband into the dark, I'd guess that something is either incorrectly dynamically generating a bit of code or there is a bit of buggy assembly in the mix somewhere.  In either case, something isn't following the ABI of the architecture correctly, leading to the crash.

Comment: The reason I'm having so much trouble understanding this is if I take the exact same code and compile it into the same project instead of a separate framework, it works fine. No errors at all.

Comment: Then look very carefully at the compiler flags on one vs. the other.   As well, consider that stack alignment problems may not cause explosions in non-dyld-trampoline contexts or if you never happen to touch libSystem.